# SugarCRM Relate a Case to a Contact record through API?

Tags: php, api, sugarcrm

I am using the SugarCRM API and I need to create a `Case` and then `Relate` it to a `Contact` record.  I have tried many combination of the code3 below and kept getting a r esult back saying no record was created for my relationship.

I finally changed it and I now get the result back saying a record is created.  The problem is when I view the Case inside SugarCRM or the Contact record, neither of them show up in each others SubPanels as if the relationship was not created!

I am also using the REST API wrapper from here https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class/

My code to relate the Case to a Contact...

```
$module_name = 'Cases';
$module_id = $caseID;
$link_field_name = 'contacts'; // Also tried 'contacts_cases' which Fails in the result
$related_ids = array('741c9e89-7f45-62e1-9490-524b21a6ea4f');//John Doe contact record 


$results = $sugar->set_relationship($module_name, $module_id, $link_field_name, $related_ids);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output from this is...

```
Array
(
    [created] => 1
    [failed] => 0
    [deleted] => 0
)
```

So you can see from my output, it appears the records are related, however when viewing the records inside SugarCRM I cannot see a relation on either modules record.  Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out.  I am posting this so if anyone else runs into this problem.

```
$related_ids = array('741c9e89-7f45-62e1-9490-524b21a6ea4f');//contact ID
```

need to be this...

```
$related_ids = '741c9e89-7f45-62e1-9490-524b21a6ea4f';//contact ID
```

Without the `array()` as the Wrapper class I am using, adds the array inside the `set_relationship()` method already!